# Docker image file location

Tags: docker

I run Docker on Windows 10 machine with WSL 2 support. I would like to know where docker image files are located in this situation? Where docker image files are located in case when no WSL 2 is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this blog post](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/where-are-docker-images-stored-docker-container-paths-explained/), Docker Desktop on Windows stores its containers *inside* another container, that container is stored in `C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop`. If you `docker inspect` a container you have setup, it will give you a Linux path, which you can then get to once you go inside the host container using `docker run -it --privileged --pid=host debian nsenter -t 1 -m -u -i sh`

This assumes you are using the default (Hyper-V) hypervisor for Docker Desktop. Where you use VMware as the hypervisor instead, different rules may apply.